# "Recursive" constants in perl

Tags: perl, constants

Is there some conviented way to use one constant when defining another constant in perl?

The following obviously does **not** work

```
use constant {
    MAIN_DIR   => "/path/to/some/dir",
    PROP_DIR => MAIN_DIR . "/sub_dir",
    PROP_FILE  => PROP_DIR . "/props.props",
};
```

The only think I could think of is multiple `use constant` lines, but it's a bit ugly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [perldoc](http://perldoc.perl.org/constant.html#Defining-multiple-constants-at-once) there is no way around that. At least not with `use constants`.

I'd go with using multiple `use` statements.

Answer (score 5):

FYI, you can use constant functions in the first place (that's how the `constants` pragma works):

```
sub MAIN_DIR  () { "/path/to/some/dir"       }
sub PROP_DIR  () { MAIN_DIR . "/sub_dir"     }
sub PROP_FILE () { PROP_DIR . "/props.props" }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -wle 'use Readonly; Readonly my $FOO => "foo"; Readonly my $FOOBAR => $FOO . "bar"; print $FOOBAR;'
foobar
```

PBP (Perl Best Practices) recommends using [Readonly](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Readonly)